# Add data to retrained Inception net

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I did few experiments with Google's Inception-v3 net from the tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html)

If I have a large enough data set, then it's fine. But what about when a data set is relatively small and is growing on the go (roughly 10% a day)?

Is there a way to add more data points to the retrained net?
I don't think that retraining a whole model each time we get a new data point doesn't seem efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of each day's data as a large batch. Tensorflow uses [SGD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) that naturally supports this kind of training input.

You can just save your model to disk after you finish each day's training and load yesterday's model before each day's traning.

Comment: Is is available to merge two models somehow?

Comment: You don't have to merge two models if your each day's training is based on the model from each yesterday's.

Answer (score 0):

There are [checkpoints](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#saving_and_restoring) in TensorFlow if you want to pause and resume. Another option is to train different categories on different layers. It's possible to use your outputs from image retraining as inputs. [Better hardware](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePVmMGkpka8&t=10s) should also be considered.